# java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: yy/ii : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, classformaterror

This is how error happened.Now i am using Eclipse Indigo integrated with apache tomcat 6.0 and also changed the default port to 9090.

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: yy/ii : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0 (unable to load class yy.ii)
    at     org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:1851)                                                                                             at     org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:890)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1354)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1233)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationServletAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:58)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.applicationAnnotationsConfig(ContextConfig.java:297)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.start(ContextConfig.java:1068)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:261)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4252)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:719)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:443)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:516)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:710)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:578)
    ... 6 more
```

Comment: Voted to move to serverfault.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you're compiling with JDK7 but running Tomcat with JDK6. One way or another, you're trying to run class files in a JVM that's older than the compiler that compiled them. Make sure to run Tomcat with the same JVM as what you run Eclipse in.

Answer (score 4):

The error is because of the `UnsupportedClassVersionError`

> at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:413)
>   Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: yy/ii : Unsupported
>   major.minor version 51.0 (unable to load class yy.ii)

JVM can only run a class file that is compiled using the same version or earlier version of Java Compiler . `UnsupportedClassVersionError` will happen if you use a lower version of JVM to run a class file that is compiled using an higher version of Java Compiler.

**Configure the java compiler version (Setting 1)**

The version of the Java Compiler is configured in the `Project  Properties ->Java Build Path-->Libraries Tab---> Select "JRE System Library" -->Edit`

All sources in your project will then be compiled using this version of Java compiler

[image: Configure the java compiler version]

**Configure WTP tomcat runtime s' JVM version (Setting 2)**

As you are using the WTP tomcat to run the project , so the JVM that is used by the WTP tomcat will run your project 's compiled class.  Its version  is configured in the `Servers View --> double click your tomcat server -->  Runtime Environment`

[image: Configure WTP tomcat runtime s' JVM version]

Please make sure the runtime  JVM version (setting 2) is not lower than the JVM version that is used to compiled your sources (setting 1)